# Typescript with React > Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm stuck on this issue whilst trying to build a project using typescript with react.
Here are the error messages from typescript.

```
Enter code hereElement implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ time: string; EC_slab1: number; EC_slab2: number; EC_drain_PC: number; WC_slab1: number; WC_slab2: number; CO2air: number; HumDef: number; Rhair: number; Tair: number; EnScr: number; BlackScr: number; ... 4 more ...; Tout: number; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ time: string; EC_slab1: number; EC_slab2: number; EC_drain_PC: number; WC_slab1: number; WC_slab2: number; CO2air: number; HumDef: number; Rhair: number; Tair: number; EnScr: number; BlackScr: number; ... 4 more ...; Tout: number; }'.  TS7053

    20 |       newObj[e] = [];
    21 |     }
  > 22 |     newObj[e].push(ele[e]);
       |                    ^
    23 |     console.log(ele[e]);
    24 |     console.log(e);
    25 |   })`
```

Seems that the errors occur inline 22 with parameter ele.

Let's say I have this:

```
declare global {
  type Dictionary<T> = { [key: string]: T };
}

let newObj: Dictionary<any> = {};
Data.dataset.forEach(ele => {
  const keys = Object.keys(ele);
  keys.forEach(e => {
    // console.log
    if(!newObj[e]){
      newObj[e] = [];
    }
    newObj[e].push(ele[e]);
  })
});

const options: Highcharts.Options = {
  title: {
      text: 'My chart'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Baby boom'
    }
},
  series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name:'a',
      data: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    name:'b',
    data: [11, 22, 3]
},{
  type: 'line',
  name:'c',
  data: [1, 23, 53]
}],
  
}

const App = (props: HighchartsReact.Props) => <div>
    <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
        {...props}
    />
</div>

export default App;
```

I tried looking everywhere on TypeScript docs, but how the heck am I suppose to interface this so it can accept ele[e]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your trying to use a string of type any as an index.

```
newObj[e].push(ele[e]);
```

Data.dataset being a `{}` dictionary when iterating forEach "ele" as key of type string and when looping keys of type number. The exception is being thrown because your trying to use a string as an index. **NOTE** if the keys in `Datadataset` are of type string, the forEach loop will print each `char` in string i.e., substring. If you are trying to copy the dictionary into a new dictionary. It can be achieved doing the following.

```
let copy_db: Dictionary<any> = {};

// Loop over all the keys in the object
for (let prop in Data.dataset) {

 // Make sure the object has this value, and not its prototype
 if (Data.dataset.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    // throws value into new dictionary
    copy_db[prop] = Data.dataset[prop];
    // if you would like an empty value in the new dictionary, then you would add a else with copy_db[prop] = [];
  }
}
```